# Block dates in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck on blocking dates in bootstrap datepicker. I need it have a range of 7 days from the starting date and blocks all the dates which is not in the 7 days

for example the user chooses 11th April 2015. That user can only select dates until 18th April 2015 which would be the ending date. Can someone please help me.

Thanks.

Here is my code for the date picker bootstrap.

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
    minDate:today,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'   
}).change(function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('maxDate', startDate+10);
});
```

Comment: first off, i spot you havent closed your function yet, your main function yet. indenting it shows you that ;)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not setting both minDate and maxDate in the options object?

Comment: @Wex Seems that '#startdate' and '#enddate' are two different datepicker. He would like '#enddate' to dynamically update as '#startdate' changes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot directly do arithmetic operations to a `Date` object. Instead, you should do this.

```
function getEndDate(date) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    return date;
}
```

Secondly, you should be able to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` options.

```
$('#startdate').datetimepicker({
    minDate: today,
    format:  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'   
}).change(function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#enddate').datetimepicker('maxDate', getEndDate(startDate));
});
```

Comment: No it still does not work. The end date calendar won't show up

Comment: @nadia Can you update the question with all the code you now have?